# array with constant size (global vs stack)

Tags: c, gcc

When I tried this code it works:

```
const int i = 5;
int main() {
    int arry[i];
}
```

Even though this didn't work:

```
const int i = 5;
int arry[i];
int main() {

}
```

I have read all posts here about arrays with constant sizes, but I can't understand why when declaring `arry` in main it works.

Comment: Define "didn't work." Did you get a compiler error, a crash, a nuclear meltdown, abducted by aliens? What did you expect to happen, what actually happened, and what information were you given as to the difference?

Comment: What is the error or warning do you see?

Comment: error: variably modified ‘array’ at file scope  this 
error comes

Comment: @cpx sad that you deleted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947739/when-is-an-identifier-a-name-in-c . If you could consider undeleting it... the answer given to that question is plain wrong!

Comment: @ssube :D Well said, dude! Perfect SO humour. We need some, at least occasionally.

Answer (score 9):

The issue here is that `const` in C doesn’t result in a true constant.

When you write `const int i = 5` what you have is a read-only variable and not a constant. In C99 an array dimensioned with `i` is a variable length array (VLA). VLAs are only available for stack allocated variables, hence the compilation error you see.

If you need an array with global scope you should switch to a macro.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5
int arry[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

This is valid because `5` is a literal which is a true constant.

In fact, even for an array of automatic storage (i.e. stack allocated local variable) you should avoid a VLA since they incur a runtime overhead.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the run-time overhead incurred by VLAs. Thanks.

Comment: @aix For a VLA `int a[i]`, the compiler has to write code that reads the value of `i` each time the function executes. For a fixed length array `int a[5]`, the compiler knows at compile time how much stack space to allocate for `a`.

Comment: Sure. It just seems a bit surprising to me that this sort of overhead would warrant blanket advice to avoid VLAs.

Comment: oh got it,VLAs are only available for stack allocated variables,...i have read your answer 5 times then i understand whole things..!

Comment: @aix You are probably right. VLAs just give me the fear. Probably my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Version 2 is simply not valid C, since `i` is a read-only variable rather than a true compile-time constant.** If you wanted to make it work, you could use `malloc` and `free` (or a `#define` for the size).

**Version 1 uses a variable-length array, which is standard feature of C99.** `gcc` supports this syntax in pre-C99 code as an extension. If you compiled your code as C90 and turned on `-pedantic`, you'd get a warning that `ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘arry’`.

Comment: You could probably elaborate more on why version 1 is not valid C.