# CUDA application .exe has stopped working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, stack-overflow

So, after finally getting my completely on-GPU integrator working correctly, I find that if I increase the dimensionality of the system I'm trying to integrate, the .exe compiles and seems like it's running but then consistently "stops working."

Potential problem - the program uses a master thread that runs the integrator and loops over the number of points I'm integrating.  I'm thinking it's this master thread, which is going to have to run the entire length of the integration (which on my python/pyCUDA version of this code typically took hours) that's causing the problems.

Another potential problem that I had considered was that changing the dimensionality of my system directly affects the number of threads launched in my kernel calls.  100 works, but 200 causes the .exe has stopped working error.  I am running on a GTX Titan, however, so I know it can launch up to 1024 threads per block, so I don't think that's the issue.

Potential solution - Now I already know about the issue here with Timeout Detection and Recovery. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx I've had this error and used the method documented here : http://http.developer.nvidia.com/ParallelNsight/2.1/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Using_CUDA_Debugger.htm to turn off WDDM using NSIGHT Monitor.  I no longer receive that specific "driver has stopped responding and has been reset" error.

No CUDA error message throws.  Pressing debug after the error shows up, I get

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x0000000013F07B0A7 in Dynamic Parallelism Test.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack Overflow : (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000193000)."
```

Sorry, not sure about the numbers of 0's.

Googling the actual meaning of our namesake site, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow, does this indicate that something weird is going on with the memory my kernels are trying to use...

**EDIT**

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>                      //display 2 decimal places
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

__global__ void rkf5(size_t, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double* , double*);
__global__ void calcK(int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k1(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k2(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k3(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k4(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k5(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k6(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrAdd(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrSub(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrMult(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrInit(double*, double);
__global__ void arrCopy(double*, double*);
__device__ void setup(double , double*, double*, double*, double*, int*);
__device__ double flux(int, double*) ;
__device__ double knowles_flux(int, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);
__device__ void calcStepSize(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*);
__global__ void storeConcs(double*, size_t, double*, int);
__global__ void takeFourthOrderStep(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void takeFifthOrderStep(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);

//Error checking that I don't understand yet.
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

//Main program.
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //std::cout << std::fixed;              //display 2 decimal places
    //std::cout << std::setprecision(8);        //display 2 decimal places

    const int maxlength = 125;              //Number of discrete concentrations we are tracking.
    int nc = 2;                             //Nucleus Size
    int n2 = 0;                             //Secondary Nucleus Size
    double ka = 5E4;        //Monomer addition rate
    double kb = 0;      //Monomer subtraction rate
    double kp = 0;      //Oligomer addition rate
    double km = 2E-8;       //Oligomer subtraction rate
    double kn = 2E-5;       //Nucleation rate
    double kn2 = 0; //Secondary nucleation rate
    double mo = 5E-6;                           //Initial concentration in M

    double concs[maxlength];                //Meant to store the current concentrations 
    double temp1[maxlength];                //Used as a bin to store products of Butcher's tableau and k values.
    double temp2[maxlength];                //Used as a bin to store products of Butcher's tableau and k values.
    double tempsum[maxlength];              //Used as a bin to store cumulative sum of tableau and k values
    double k1s[maxlength];
    double k2s[maxlength];
    double k3s[maxlength];
    double k4s[maxlength];
    double k5s[maxlength];
    double k6s[maxlength];
    const int numpoints = 1000;     
    double to = 0;                          //Beginning integration time in seconds
    double tf = 5;                          //Final integration time in seconds
    double dt = (tf-to)/static_cast<double>(numpoints); //Static step size in seconds
    double concStorage[maxlength][numpoints];   //Stores concs [rows] vs. time [columns]

    //Initialize all the arrays on the host to ensure arrays of 0's are sent to the device.
    //Also, here is where we can seed the system.
    std::cout<<dt;
    std::cout<<"\n";
    concs[0]=mo;
    std::cout<<concs[0];
    std::cout<<" ";
    for (int i=0; i<maxlength; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<numpoints; j++)
            concStorage[i][j]=0;
        concs[i]=0;
        temp1[i]=0;
        temp2[i]=0;
        tempsum[i]=0;
        k1s[i]=0;
        k2s[i]=0;
        k3s[i]=0;
        k4s[i]=0;
        k5s[i]=0;
        k6s[i]=0;
        //std::cout<<concs[i];
        //std::cout<<" ";
    }
    concs[0]=mo;
    std::cout<<"\n";

    //Define all the pointers to device array memory addresses. These contain the on-GPU
    //addresses of all the data we're generating/using.
    double *d_concStorage;
    double *d_temp1;
    double *d_temp2;
    double *d_tempsum;
    double *d_k1s;
    double *d_k2s;
    double *d_k3s;
    double *d_k4s;
    double *d_k5s;
    double *d_k6s;
    int *d_numpoints;
    int *d_maxlength;
    int *d_nc;              
    int *d_n2;
    double *d_ka;       
    double *d_kb;       
    double *d_kp;       
    double *d_km;       
    double *d_kn;   
    double *d_kn2;
    double *d_concs;

    double *d_dt;
    double *d_to;
    double *d_tf;


    //Calculate all the sizes of the arrays in order to allocate the proper amount of memory on the GPU.
    //A lot of these can be simplified to "sizeof(double)" etc
    size_t size_temp1 = sizeof(temp1);
    size_t size_temp2 = sizeof(temp2);
    size_t size_tempsum = sizeof(tempsum);
    size_t size_ks = sizeof(k1s);
    size_t size_numpoints = sizeof(numpoints);
    size_t size_maxlength = sizeof(maxlength);
    size_t size_nc = sizeof(nc);
    size_t size_n2 = sizeof(n2);
    size_t size_ka = sizeof(ka);
    size_t size_kb = sizeof(kb);
    size_t size_kp = sizeof(kp);
    size_t size_km = sizeof(km);
    size_t size_kn = sizeof(kn);
    size_t size_kn2 = sizeof(kn2);
    size_t size_concs = sizeof(concs);

    size_t size_dt = sizeof(dt);
    size_t size_to = sizeof(to);
    size_t size_tf = sizeof(tf);
    size_t h_pitch = numpoints*sizeof(double);
    size_t d_pitch;

    //Calculate the "pitch" of the 2D array.  The pitch is basically the length of a 2D array's row.  IT's larger 
    //than the actual row full of data due to hadware issues.  We thusly will use the pitch instead of the data 
    //size to traverse the array.
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_concStorage, &d_pitch, numpoints * sizeof(double), maxlength)); 

    //Allocate memory on the GPU for all the arrrays we're going to use in the integrator.

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_temp1, size_temp1));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_temp2, size_temp1));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_tempsum, size_tempsum));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k1s, size_ks));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k2s, size_ks));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k3s, size_ks));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k4s, size_ks));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k5s, size_ks));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k6s, size_ks));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_numpoints, size_numpoints));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_maxlength, size_maxlength));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_nc, size_nc));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_n2, size_n2));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ka, size_ka));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_kb, size_kb));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_kp, size_kp));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_km, size_km));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_kn, size_kn));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_kn2, size_kn2));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_concs, size_concs));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dt, size_dt));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_to, size_to));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_tf, size_tf));

    //Copy all initial values of arrays to GPU.
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(d_concStorage, d_pitch, concStorage, h_pitch, numpoints*sizeof(double), maxlength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_temp1, &temp1, size_temp1, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_temp2, &temp2, size_temp2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_tempsum, &tempsum, size_tempsum, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_k1s, &k1s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_k2s, &k2s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_k3s, &k3s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_k4s, &k4s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_k5s, &k5s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_k6s, &k6s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_numpoints, &numpoints, size_numpoints, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_maxlength, &maxlength, size_maxlength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_nc, &nc, size_nc, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_n2, &n2, size_n2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_ka, &ka, size_ka, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_kb, &kb, size_kb, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_kp, &kp, size_kp, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_km, &km, size_km, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_kn, &kn, size_kn, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_kn2, &kn2, size_kn2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_concs, &concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_dt, &dt, size_dt, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_to, &to, size_to, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_tf, &tf, size_tf, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    //Run the integrator.
    //gpuErrchk(cudaSetDevice(1));
    rkf5<<<1,1>>>(d_pitch, d_concStorage, d_temp1, d_temp2, d_tempsum, d_k1s, d_k2s, d_k3s, d_k4s, d_k5s, d_k6s, d_numpoints, d_maxlength, d_nc, d_n2, d_ka, d_kb, d_kp, d_km, d_kn, d_kn2, d_concs, d_dt);
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Copy 2D array of concentrations vs. time from GPU to Host.
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy2D(concStorage, h_pitch, d_concStorage, d_pitch, numpoints*sizeof(double), maxlength, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );   

    /*
    //Old arrays used to compare known value of e with calculated value of e.
    //Blah.

    double a[10];
    double b[10];
    double c[10];
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
        b[i]=0;
        c[i]=0;
    }
    */

    //Print out the concStorage array after the kernel runs.  Used to test that the 2D array transferred correctly from host to GPU and back.
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Calculated Array";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i=0; i<maxlength; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<numpoints; j++)
        {
            if (j%(numpoints/10)==0)
            {
                //a[j/(numpoints/10)]=concStorage[i][j];
                std::cout<<concStorage[i][j];
                std::cout<<"   ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    cudaDeviceReset();  //Clean up all memory.
    /*
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing.";
    myfile.close();
    */

    return 0;
}
//Main kernel.  This is mean to be run as a master thread that calls all the other functions and thusly "runs" the integrator.
__global__ void rkf5(size_t pitch, double* concStorage, double* temp1, double* temp2, double* tempsum, double* k1s, double* k2s, double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s, double* k6s, int* numpoints, int* maxlength, int* nc, int* n2, double* ka, double* kb, double* kp, double* km, double* kn, double* kn2, double* concs, double* dt)
{
    /*
    axy variables represent the coefficients in the Butcher's tableau where x represents the order of the step and the y value corresponds to the ky value 
    the coefficient gets multiplied by.  Have to cast them all as doubles, or the ratios evaluate as integers.
    e.g. a21 -> a21 * k1
    e.g. a31 -> a31 * k1 + a32 * k2
    */
    double a21 = static_cast<double>(.25);

    double a31 = static_cast<double>(3)/static_cast<double>(32);
    double a32 = static_cast<double>(9)/static_cast<double>(32);

    double a41 = static_cast<double>(1932)/static_cast<double>(2197);
    double a42 = static_cast<double>(-7200)/static_cast<double>(2197);
    double a43 = static_cast<double>(7296)/static_cast<double>(2197);

    double a51 = static_cast<double>(439)/static_cast<double>(216);
    double a52 = static_cast<double>(-8);
    double a53 = static_cast<double>(3680)/static_cast<double>(513);
    double a54 = static_cast<double>(-845)/static_cast<double>(4104);

    double a61 = static_cast<double>(-8)/static_cast<double>(27);
    double a62 = static_cast<double>(2);
    double a63 = static_cast<double>(-3544)/static_cast<double>(2565);
    double a64 = static_cast<double>(1859)/static_cast<double>(4104);
    double a65 = static_cast<double>(-11)/static_cast<double>(40);

    //for loop that integrates over the specified number of points. Actually, might have to make it a do-while loop for adaptive step sizes 
    //for(int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
    for(int k = 0; k < *numpoints; k++)
    {
        if (k!=0)
        {
            arrCopy<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, tempsum);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        }
        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(temp1, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(temp2, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, concs, k1s, dt);             //k1 = dt * flux (concs)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //Sync here because kernel continues onto next line before k1 finished

        setup(a21, temp1, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);      //tempsum = a21*k1
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, tempsum, tempsum);   //tempsum = concs + a21*k1    
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, tempsum, k2s, dt);           //k2 = dt * flux (concs + a21*k1)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        setup(a31, temp1, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);      //temp1sum = a31*k1
        setup(a32, temp1, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);      //tempsum = a31*k1 + a32*k2
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, tempsum, tempsum);   //tempsum = concs + a31*k1 + a32*k2
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, tempsum, k3s, dt);           //k3 = dt * flux (concs + a31*k1 + a32*k2)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        setup(a41, temp1, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);      //tempsum = a41*k1
        setup(a42, temp1, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);      //tempsum = a41*k1 + a42*k2
        setup(a43, temp1, tempsum, k3s, concs, maxlength);      //tempsum = a41*k1 + a42*k2 + a43*k3
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, tempsum, tempsum);   //tempsum = concs + a41*k1 + a42*k2 + a43*k3
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, tempsum, k4s, dt);           //k4 = dt * flux (concs + a41*k1 + a42*k2 + a43*k3)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        setup(a51, temp1, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a51*k1
        setup(a52, temp1, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a51*k1 + a52*k2
        setup(a53, temp1, tempsum, k3s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3
        setup(a54, temp1, tempsum, k4s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3 + a54*k4
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, tempsum, tempsum);   //tempsum = concs + a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3 + a54*k4
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, tempsum, k5s, dt);           //k5 = dt * flux (concs + a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3 + a54*k4)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, 0);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        setup(a61, temp1, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a61*k1
        setup(a62, temp1, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2
        setup(a63, temp1, tempsum, k3s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3
        setup(a64, temp1, tempsum, k4s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4
        setup(a65, temp1, tempsum, k5s, concs, maxlength);  //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4 + a65*k5
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, tempsum, tempsum);   //tempsum = concs + a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4 + a65*k5
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, tempsum, k6s, dt);           //k6 = dt * flux (concs + a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4 + a65*k5)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        //At this point, temp1 and tempsum are maxlength dimension arrays that are able to be used for other things.

        //Calculate acceptable step size before storing the concentrations.
        calcStepSize(temp1, temp2, tempsum, concs, k1s, k2s, k3s, k4s, k5s, k6s, dt, maxlength);    //temp1 = 4th Order guess, tempsum = 5th Order guess
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        //Store the initial conditions in the first column of the storage array.
        if (k==0)
        {
            storeConcs<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concStorage, pitch, concs, k);  //Store this step's concentrations in 2D array
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        }
        //Store future concentration in next column of storage array.
        storeConcs<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concStorage, pitch, tempsum, k+1);  //Store this step's concentrations in 2D array
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
}
//calcStepSize will take in an error tolerance, the current concentrations and the k values and calculate the resulting step size according to the following equation
//e[n+1]=y4[n+1] - y5[n+1]
__device__ void calcStepSize(double* temp1, double*temp2, double* tempsum, double* concs, double* k1s, double* k2s, double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s, double* k6s, double* dt, int* maxlength)
{
    //do
    //{
        takeFourthOrderStep<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(temp1, concs, k1s, k2s, k3s, k4s, k5s);            //Store 4th order guess in temp1
        takeFifthOrderStep<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, concs, k1s, k2s, k3s, k4s, k5s, k6s);  //Store 5th order guess in tempsum
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        //arrSub<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(temp1, tempsum, temp2)
        //arrMin<<< 1, *maxlength >>>
    //arrMult
    //}
    //while
}
//takeFourthOrderStep is going to overwrite the old temp1 array with the new array of concentrations that result from a 4th order step.  This kernel is meant to be launched 
// with as many threads as there are discrete concentrations to be tracked.
__global__ void takeFourthOrderStep(double* y4, double* concs, double* k1s, double* k2s, double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s)
{
    double b41 = static_cast<double>(25)/static_cast<double>(216);
    double b42 = static_cast<double>(0);
    double b43 = static_cast<double>(1408)/static_cast<double>(2565);
    double b44 = static_cast<double>(2197)/static_cast<double>(4104);
    double b45 = static_cast<double>(-1)/static_cast<double>(5);
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    y4[idx] = concs[idx] + b41 * k1s[idx] + b42 * k2s[idx] + b43 * k3s[idx] + b44 * k4s[idx] + b45 * k5s[idx];
}
//takeFifthOrderStep is going to overwrite the old array of concentrations with the new array of concentrations.  As of now, this will be the 5th order step.  Another function can be d
//defined that will take a fourth order step if that is interesting for any reason.  This kernel is meant to be launched with as many threads as there are discrete concentrations
//to be tracked.
//Store b values in register? Constants?
__global__ void takeFifthOrderStep(double* y5, double* concs, double* k1s, double* k2s, double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s, double* k6s)
{
    double b51 = static_cast<double>(16)/static_cast<double>(135);
    double b52 = static_cast<double>(0);
    double b53 = static_cast<double>(6656)/static_cast<double>(12825);
    double b54 = static_cast<double>(28561)/static_cast<double>(56430);
    double b55 = static_cast<double>(-9)/static_cast<double>(50);
    double b56 = static_cast<double>(2)/static_cast<double>(55);
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    y5[idx] = concs[idx] + b51 * k1s[idx] + b52 * k2s[idx] + b53 * k3s[idx] + b54 * k4s[idx] + b55 * k5s[idx] + b56 * k6s[idx];
}
//storeConcs takes the current array of concentrations and stores it in the cId'th column of the 2D concStorage array
//pitch = memory size of a row
__global__ void storeConcs(double* cS, size_t pitch, double* concs, int cId)
{
    int tIdx = threadIdx.x;
    //cS is basically the memory address of the first element of the flattened (1D) 2D array.
    double* row = (double*)((char*)cS + tIdx * pitch);
    row[cId] = concs[tIdx];
}
//Perhaps I can optimize by using shared memory to hold conc values.
__global__ void calcK(int* maxlength, int* nc, int* n2, double* ka, double* kb, double* kp, double* km, double* kn, double* kn2, double* concs, double* ks, double* dt)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    ks[idx]=(*dt)*knowles_flux(idx, maxlength, nc, n2, ka, kb, kp, km, kn, kn2, concs);
}
//Adds two arrays (a + b) element by element and stores the result in array c.
__global__ void arrAdd(double* a, double* b, double* c)
{                                                 
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[idx]=a[idx]+b[idx];
}
//Subtracts two arrays (a - b) element by element and stores the result in array c.
__global__ void arrSub(double* a, double* b, double* c)
{                                                 
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[idx]=a[idx]-b[idx];
}
//Multiplies two arrays (a * b) element by element and stores the result in array c.
__global__ void arrMult(double* a, double* b, double* c)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[idx]=a[idx]*b[idx];
}
//Will find the min of errors array.
__global__ void arrMin(double* errors)
{
    //extern _shared_ double[7];
}
//Initializes an array a to double value b.
__global__ void arrInit(double* a, double b)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    a[idx]=b;
}
//Copies array b onto array a.
__global__ void arrCopy(double* a, double* b)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    a[idx]=b[idx];
}
//Placeholder function for the flux calculation.  It will take the size of the oligomer and current concentrations as inputs.
__device__ double flux(int r, double *concs) 
{
    return -concs[r];
}
//This function multiplies a tableau value by the corresponding k array and adds the result to tempsum.  Used to
//add all the a*k terms. concs not necessary
//e.g. setup(a21, temp1, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength) => tempsum = a21 * k1
__device__ void setup(double tableauValue, double *temp1, double *tempsum, double *ks, double *concs, int *maxlength) 
{
    //Sets tempsum to tabVal * k
    arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(temp1, tableauValue);      //Set [temp1] to tableau value, temp1 = a
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    arrMult<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(ks, temp1, temp1);         //Multiply tableau value by appropriate [k], temp1 = a*k
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, temp1, tempsum);   //Move tabVal*k to [tempsum], tempsum = tempsum+temp1
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //temp1 = tableauValue * kArray
    //tempsum = current sum (tableauValue * kArray)
}

//I need to use constants and replace these for loops with dynamic reductions.
__device__ double knowles_flux(int r, int* maxlength, int* nc, int* n2, double* ka, double* kb, double* kp, double* km, double* kn, double* kn2, double *conc)
{
    double frag_term = 0;
    double flux = 0;
    if (r == ((*maxlength)-1))
        {
        flux = -(*km)*(r)*conc[r]+2*(*ka)*conc[r-1]*conc[0];
        }
    else if (r > ((*nc)-1))
        {
        for (int s = r+1; s < (*maxlength); s++)
            {
            frag_term += conc[s];
            }
        flux = -(*km)*(r)*conc[r] + 2*(*km)*frag_term - 2*(*ka)*conc[r]*conc[0] + 2*(*ka)*conc[r-1]*conc[0];
        }
    else if (r == ((*nc)-1))
        {
        for (int s = r+1; s < (*maxlength); s++)
            {
            frag_term += conc[s];
            }
        flux = (*kn)*pow(conc[0],(*nc)) + 2*(*km)*frag_term - 2*(*ka)*conc[r]*conc[0];
        }
    else if (r < ((*nc)-1))
        {
        flux = 0;
        }
    return flux;
}
```

Comment: Is the Titan you display GPU?

Comment: @talonmies Ah, that's another issue.  I have two Titans.  I was trying to figure out how to use cudaSetDevice() to make on of the GPU's my dedicated compute GPUs. In the Nvidia display properties I have CUDA enabled on (2 of 2), but I'm sure that's not enough to guarantee that Titan 2 of 2 is not my display GPU or that the code is even running on that GPU.

Comment: You can't "turn off WDDM" on a GTX titan using nsight or any other tool.  The page you linked (from a pretty old version of the documentation - I assume you're not using nsight VSE 2.1) only references WDDM with respect to the TDR mechanism.  The unhandled exception and "stack overflow" message are referring to code that is running on the CPU, not on the GPU.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I thought the setting of the flag to "disabled" in Nsight Monitor turned of TDR.

Comment: turning off TDR and turning off WDDM are two separate things.  Your GPU is still in WDDM mode.  I don't think this discussion is central to understanding whatever issue you are facing.  It's not even clear that the problem you've described has anything to do with CUDA.  Without a reproducer or a lot more information, I'm not sure how much guidance you may be able to get.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Should I post my code again?   I've been trying to use VS2012 to debug this, but the last thing the debugger points to tells me after the stack overflow is "Access violation writing location."  The debugger in the call stack then points to the first line of main().  chkstk.asm not found.  The more I read, the more it seems like this is something trying to reference memory that isn't being used.

Comment: Sure, I think posting a complete reproducer is always a good thing on SO.  I'm not saying I can sort it out for you, but I think you're more likely to get good help that way.  Are you creating stack variables (in host code) that might be scaled in some way by the thread count?

Comment: Ok, cool. I just didn't know what you mean by "reproducer."  Changing the thread count (maxlength in my code) changes the sizes of many 1 x maxlength arrays and a 2D maxlength x numpoints array.

Comment: A reproducer is a complete, compilable piece of code that reproduces the problem.  Ideally it follows the guidelines of SSCCE.org  It is preferably not your entire code base, if that is large, but rather the minimum subset of that code that is complete, compilable, and will reproduce (ie. show, demonstrate) the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was finally able to run down this issue.  So, if anyone is running into a similar error, hopefully this will help you out.

Note, in my code, I am working with a two dimensional array, concStorage[maxlengths][numpoints].  As prompted by Robert Crovella, the problem is with my CPU code and has to do with stack variables.  Naturally, I didn't know what a stack variable was, but the stack has limited memory available to it (~1MB) and when you define arrays in functions, they use up that storage.  Here's are a pair of links that helped me out.

This one helped me realize that it was the array that was causing my stack overflow.
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/296695-stack-overflow-in-my-code-but-where/

This one helped me fix it.
[array with constant size (global vs stack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946415/array-with-constant-size-global-vs-stack)

**Solution:** Under my #includes outside main(), I #define'd

```
#define MAXLENGTH 2000
#define NUMPOINTS 1000
double concStorage[MAXLENGTH][NUMPOINTS];   //Stores concs [rows] vs. time [columns]
```

Which allows me to run without a crash.  My understanding is that this variable is now on the heap instead of the stack.  Now what I'd like to know is I should move all the arrays out of main() like with concStorage, but as far as this issue, it seems solved for now.

Comment: Moving arrays outside of `main` should not be necessary.  That does change the storage class from stack to something else apparently, but I don't know if it's heap storage.  Anyway, within your application, if you use `malloc` to create the storage, e.g. `double *concStorage = (double *)malloc(MAXLENGTH*NUMPOINTS*sizeof(double));`, that storage will be allocated out of the heap.  This will have some other implementation issues for arrays of dimensionality higher than 1D, which I won't try to go into in comments, but you'll find many questions/answers on SO that cover these topics.